# Problem with jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions:

```
$(function() {
    $(".deactivated").click(function() {           
          var Container = $(this).parent();             
       var id = $(this).attr("id");             
        var string = 'id='+ id ;    
        $.ajax({   
            url: "<?php echo site_url('social/activate') ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
                 success: function(){
                     Container.fadeOut(1000, function(){
                     $(this).load("<?php echo site_url('social/social_icon') ?>", {id: id}, function(){
                         $(this).hide().fadeIn(700);
                         $(this).click();
                     })
                 });
            }   
        });
        return false;
    });
});

 $(function() {
    $(".activated").click(function() {           
          var Container = $(this).parent();             
       var id = $(this).attr("id");             
        var string = 'id='+ id ;    
        $.ajax({   
            url: "<?php echo site_url('social/deactivate') ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
                 success: function(){
                     Container.fadeOut(1000, function(){
                     $(this).load("<?php echo site_url('social/social_icon') ?>", {id: id}, function(){
                         $(this).hide().fadeIn(700);
                     })
                 });
            }   
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

One is to activate link and other is to deactivate it. Functions are working fine, but when link is activated or deactivated, it can't be clicked again to change it (page needs to be refreshed in order for functions to work again). What I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Are you changing the class of the links?! deactivated=> activated and activated => deactivated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$(".activated").click(function() {
$(".deactivated").click(function() {
```

To:

```
$(".activated").live('click',function() {  
$(".deactivated").live('click',function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be replacing the container and the elements inside it, so the elements that had the `click` events bound to them will have been removed.

You can fix this by changing your event handlers to use `live`:

```
$(".deactivated").live('click', function() {
```

and

```
$(".activated").live('click', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're replacing the links that you click which loses the event bindings.

Change the .click() to use .live('click'..

```
$(".deactivated").live('click', function() {
```